# c# use comboboxes to filter sql data

Tags: c#, sql, listview, combobox

I have a winforms app in C# with several `comboboxes`. these comboboxes display data from an SQL database. I can get the comboboxes to display the data in a `listview`, but what I want is to filter the data. 
For example, the user selects a value in combobox1 and the results appear, but when he selects a value in `combobox` 2 only the corresponding values with the rules from `combobox1` will be displayed.
it´s like creating a filter, but I cant figure out how I can interact between the comboboxes.
The code I have is:

```
 private void desempenho_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"select [desc],[enchimento],[compo] from vidros where desempenho = @emp", con);
            sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@emp", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = desempenho.Text;
            DataTable DTT = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(DTT);
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < DTT.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = DTT.Rows[i];
                ListViewItem listitem = new ListViewItem(dr["desc"].ToString());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["enchimento"].ToString());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["compo"].ToString());
                listView1.Items.Add(listitem);
            }
        }
        private void valu_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter SDA2 = new SqlDataAdapter(@"select [desc],[enchimento],[compo] from vidros where valu = @emp2", con);
            SDA2.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@emp2", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = valu.Text;
            DataTable DTT2 = new DataTable();
            SDA2.Fill(DTT2);
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < DTT2.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = DTT2.Rows[i];
                ListViewItem listitem = new ListViewItem(dr["desc"].ToString());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["enchimento"].ToString());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["compo"].ToString());
                listView1.Items.Add(listitem);
            }
```

This is only for two of the comboboxes, but when I get this one working the rest will be simple.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Rather than repeat the SelectedIndexChanged code in each event, you should have one event handler that you call from each combo which examines the value of all the combos combo and builds the resultset from that data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do something of what you need.  Its pseudo and untested code but will iterate through each of the combo boxes on your form and then you can do what you want with the value in the list

```
void Main()
{
var cb1 = new ComboBox()
var cb2 = new ComboBox()
var frm = new Form()

var selectedItemAndValue = new List<selectedItem>();

foreach (Control ctrl in frm.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(ComboBox)
    {
        var cb = ctrl as ComboBox
        selectedItemAndValue.Add(new selectedItem {
        Idx = cb.SelectedIndex, 
        Text = cb.SelectedText, 
        Value = cb.SelectedValue.ToString()})

    }

    //the above code will then give you a list of everything that is selected in each of your combo boxes
}
}

public class selectedItem
{

public int Idx { get; set; }
public string Text { get; set; }
public string Value {get; set;}
}



// Define other methods and classes here
```